# Only allow Factory method to instantiate objects (prevent instantiation of base class AND uninitialized objects)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a base class for handling "jobs". A factory method creates derived "job handler" objects according to job type and ensures the job handler objects are initialized with all the job information.

**Calling factory method to request a handler for Job and Person assigned:**

```
public enum Job { Clean, Cook, CookChicken }; // List of jobs.

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    HandlerBase handler;
    handler = HandlerBase.CreateJobHandler(Job.Cook, "Bob");
    handler.DoJob();
    handler = HandlerBase.CreateJobHandler(Job.Clean, "Alice");
    handler.DoJob();
    handler = HandlerBase.CreateJobHandler(Job.CookChicken, "Sue");
    handler.DoJob();
  }
```

**The Result:**

```
Bob is cooking.
Alice is cleaning.
Sue is cooking.
Sue is cooking chicken.
```

**Job handler classes:**

```
public class CleanHandler : HandlerBase
{
  protected CleanHandler(HandlerBase handler) : base(handler) { }
  public override void DoJob()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is cleaning.", Person);
  }
}

public class CookHandler : HandlerBase
{
  protected CookHandler(HandlerBase handler) : base(handler) { }
  public override void DoJob()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is cooking.", Person);
  }
}
```

**A sub-classed Job Handler:**

```
public class CookChickenHandler : CookHandler
{
  protected CookChickenHandler(HandlerBase handler) : base(handler) { }
  public override void DoJob()
  {
    base.DoJob();
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is cooking chicken.", Person);
  }
}
```

**The best way of doing things? I have struggled with these issues:**

1. Ensure that all derived objects have a fully initialized base object (Person assigned).
2. Prevent instantiation of ANY objects other than through my factory method that performs all the initialization.
3. Prevent instantiation of the base class object.

## The Job handler `HandlerBase` base class:

1. A `Dictionary<Job,Type>` maps Jobs to Handler classes.
2. PRIVATE setter for job data (i.e., Person) prevents access except by factory method.
3. NO default constructor and PRIVATE constructor prevents construction except by factory method.
4. A protected "copy constructor" is the only non-private constructor. One must have an instantiated HandlerBase to create a new object, and only the base class factory can create a base HandlerBase object. The "copy constructor" throws an exception if one attempts to create new objects from a non-base object (again, preventing construction except by the factory method).

A look at the base class:

```
public class HandlerBase
{
  // Dictionary maps Job to proper HandlerBase type.
  private static Dictionary<Job, Type> registeredHandlers =
    new Dictionary<Job, Type>() {
      { Job.Clean, typeof(CleanHandler) },
      { Job.Cook, typeof(CookHandler) },
      { Job.CookChicken, typeof(CookChickenHandler) }
    };

  // Person assigned to job. PRIVATE setter only accessible to factory method.
  public string Person { get; private set; }

  // PRIVATE constructor for data initialization only accessible to factory method.
  private HandlerBase(string name) { this.Person = name; }

  // Non-private "copy constructor" REQUIRES an initialized base object.
  // Only the factory method can make a HandlerBase object.
  protected HandlerBase(HandlerBase handler)
  {
    // Prevent creating new objects from non-base objects.
    if (handler.GetType() != typeof(HandlerBase))
      throw new ArgumentException("THAT'S ILLEGAL, PAL!");

    this.Person = handler.Person; // peform "copy"
  }

  // FACTORY METHOD.
  public static HandlerBase CreateJobHandler(Job job, string name)
  {
    // Look up job handler in dictionary.
    Type handlerType = registeredHandlers[job];

    // Create "seed" base object to enable calling derived constructor.
    HandlerBase seed = new HandlerBase(name);

    object[] args = new object[] { seed };
    BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

    HandlerBase newInstance = (HandlerBase)Activator
      .CreateInstance(handlerType, flags, null, args, null);

    return newInstance;
  }

  public virtual void DoJob() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

**A look at the Factory Method:**

Because I have made public construction of a new object impossible without already having an instantiated base object, the factory method first constructs a `HandlerBase` instance as a "seed" for calling the needed derived class "copy constructor".

The factory method uses `Activator.CreateInstance()` to instantiate new objects. Activator.CreateInstance() looks for a constructor that matches the requested signature:

The desired constructor is `DerivedHandler(HandlerBase handler)`, thus,

1. My "seed" `HandlerBase` object is placed in `object[] args`.
2. I combine `BindingFlags.Instance` and `BindingFlags.NonPublic` so that CreateInstance() searches for a non-public constructor (add `BindingFlags.Public` to find a public constructor).
3. Activator.CreateInstance() instantiates the new object which is returned.

## What I don't like...

Constructors are not enforced when implementing an interface or class. The constructor code in the derived classes is mandatory:

```
protected DerivedJobHandler(HandlerBase handler) : base(handler) { }
```

Yet, if the constructor is left out you don't get a friendly compiler error telling you the exact method signature needed: "'DerivedJobHandler' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments".

It is also possible to write a constructor that eliminates any compiler error, instead--WORSE!--resulting in a run-time error:

```
protected DerivedJobHandler() : base(null) { }
```

I do not like that there is no means of enforcing a required constructor in derived class implementations.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this in general, but as you point out, constructor *can't* be made to conform in an interface. One solution to this is just require a default constructor (can be enforced in generics with use of `with T : new()`) and then an `Init` method or similar for the "real initialization" which would be part of an interface.

Comment: @pst In my "production" code I settled on a "Settings" property in the base class (no init needed, just a value struct). The derived objects don't need to implement anything since Settings is part of the base. No interface needed. I'm confused by the generics/default-constructor suggestion (same as @Jason suggested below). I can see value to enforcing a default new(), but doesn't that require the consuming code to know the type of the derived class? Instead of `HandlerBase` it would have to specify type `HandlerBase<Job1Handler>`??? Maybe I have something to learn yet here...

Comment: @pst My prior question that led me to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559662/c-force-derived-class-to-implement-base-class-contructor-with-parameters

Comment: With the default constructor restriction, imagine that instead of `new Dictionary<Job,Type> {...}`, types are mapped with a function: `void addJobMapping<T>(T job, Type type) where T : Job, new()`. This still doesn't make sure it's a valid "type", but that can be enforced in the method or taking in an *object* which conforms to `HandlerBase<T>` or similar. In the end, C# isn't a pure language nor can it describe everything in the type system. Sometimes non-compile-time-enforced contracts and unit testing must be relied upon. Happy coding.

Comment: `void addJobMapping<T>(T job, BaseHandle<T> base) where T : Job, new()` might be the function signature taking in the typed handler. However, the signature of `registeredHandlers` would be `Dictionary<Job, BaseHandler>`, where `BaseHandler<T> : BaseHandler`. Note that is is thus the *function* which is thus required to ensure the compile-time type safety (and assumes it is the only method to add new handlers).

Comment: @pst: I'm actually using reflection to discover handlers that implement the base class (no `addJobMapping()` method). I suppose I could do deeper reflection to probe for proper constructor signature. FYI-- about half of this is just learning exercise, my production code is less fancy. Need some time to absorb/experiment with your suggestion...some of us are at work today... Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three responsibilities in your HandlerBase that, if decoupled from one another, may simplify the design problem.

1. Registration of handlers
2. Construction of handlers
3. DoJob

One way of reorganizing this would be to put #1 and #2 on a factory class, and #3 on a class with an internal constructor so that only the factory class can call it per your internal requirements. You can pass in the Person and Job values directly rather than letting the constructor pull them from a different HandlerBase instance, which would make the code easier to understand.

Once these responsibilities are separated, you can then more easily evolve them independently.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you say "I want to enforce x, but the code won't do it for me" Then a unit test is generally the answer.

Then the next person who comes in to make a handler will look at the tests and know what he needs to do to conform. You could even write a unit test that looped over that dictionary of registered handlers and constructed each one. Failure to create the right constructor for a new one would fail that test.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enforce a parameterless constructor, you can just do this:

```
class Base<T> where T : new() { } 

class Derived : Base<Derived> {
    public Derived() { } // required!
}
```

Beyond parameterless, there's nothing else that you do at compile-time.

Comment: I'm confused by your post. I have actually suppressed public constructors so that only the base class factory method can create new objects. I also see no case for using generics as the consuming code should not have to be aware of the type of "job handler" object returned by the factory (other than it is derived from HandlerBase). In theory, an anonymous type could be returned. HOWEVER, my solution requires the derived class to implement a particular constructor--and I find it annoying that there is no way to enforce this signature (like when implementing an interface).

Comment: @Kevin R: Confused? There is NOTHING that you can do at compile-time in terms of enforcing the existence of particular constructors except for a parameterless constructor. I find a few things ugly about your code and think with a redesign you can avoid the problem. In particular, the base class should not be serving as a factory class for its derived classes. So it represents a common abstraction for the handlers AND it creates them? No, that violates SRP.

Comment: Thank you. Criticism is good. I do understand lack of constructor enforcement--did you overlook my design GOALS? (1) DISALLOW default constructors (prevent creation outside factory) to ensure init ONLY by the factory. (2) ELIMINATE outside knowledge of types (consumer requests a job handler, NOT a type). Opposite of your generics suggestion? SRP: The factory MUST be implemented in the base to access the private constructor. Weak SRP is static factory vs instance base members. Note: `System.Net.WebRequest' class also combines base and factory. Are my GOALS bad? Why? Again, thanks much!