# Make sure a class has a property ( and initialised via the constructor? )

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

I have the following interface and classes using C# 10:

```
public interface IStrategy {
  String Name { get; }
}

public abstract class Strategy : IStrategy {
  public abstract String Name { get; }
}

public class WeeklyStrategy : Strategy {

  public override String Name => "Weekly Strategy";

  public Options Options { get; }

  public WeeklyStrategy(Options options) {
    Options = options;
  }

}
```

How to force all `Strategy` derived classes (Ex: `WeeklyStrategy`) has a property `Options`?

And can I force that property to be initialised through the class constructor?

Comment: You can either make that an abstract property on `Strategy`, or make it a non-abstract property and define a constructor on `Strategy` which assigns to it

Comment: `Options` can just be an abstract property, but regarding the constructor, is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559662/force-derived-class-to-implement-base-class-constructor-with-parameters) what you are asking?